# When to tune hyperparameters in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, aws, sagemaker

I am currently playing around with different CNN and LSTM model architectures for my multivariate time series classification problem.

I can achieve validation accuracy of better than 50%. I would like to lock down an exact architecture at some stage instead of experimenting endlessly. In order to decide this, I want to also tune my hyperparameters.

Question:
How do I balance the need to experiment with different models, such as standalone CNN and CNN with LSTM against hyperparameter tuning? Is there such a thing as premature optimization?

I am running my training on AWS SageMaker and I can work in parallel if needed.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For specific models, there is some hyper-parameter optimization algorithm and some toolbox that do it.
If I say the famous one, the grid search is a well-known(but not optimum) algorithm for hyperparameter optimization. For more info you can visit this [**page**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization)

Moreover, you can find a good tutorial in this [**page1**](https://machinelearningmastery.com/hyperparameter-optimization-with-random-search-and-grid-search/) or [**page2**](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyperparameters-optimization-526348bb8e2d)

but for cascading some architectures and testing them, you must design architecture and then tune it by above-mentioned algorithm. I may be led you to the optimum model for your deserved task.

Comment: So if I get it correctly, I should do at least some sort of optimization on a specific architecture and then move to a different one?

Comment: yes, absolutely. That's right. moreover, to find a good solution ASAP, you can study the models that are used for similar cases. It could be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

##### As a rule of thumb:

1. To begin with, try to reuse a model architecture that already works. This can be sourced in the existing literature on the type of problem you are working with.
2. Batch size: Usually, the right batch size will be the largest one that supported by the available hardware.
3. Initial Configuration (architecture, optimiser, steps): Start with simple (default parameters of hyperparameters e.g., learning rate) and reasonable (low resource consumption) strategy.

   - **Architecture**: smaller than bigger architecture for faster training
   - **Optimizer**: start with the most popular optimiser for the type of problem and experiment with ***all*** hyperparameters of that particular optimizer according to your budget (time, compute). This is especially importan at early stages.
   - **Steps**: fine balance between performance improvement and time/compute budget. You could utilise a "delta" parameter for early stopping that indicates your threshold of what is considered an improvement.

This is a high level summary of an excellent tuning guide which you can find [here](https://github.com/google-research/tuning_playbook).